# How to create a .gephi file in networkX

Tags: python, networkx, gephi

I cannot create a .graph file from Python and the only thing that I can create is a `.gexf` file with:

```
networkx.write_gexf(graph, "test.gexf")
```

It didn't work with:

```
networkx.write_gexf(graph, "test.gephi")
```

Comment: No it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [networkX documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.gexf.write_gexf.html?highlight=write_gexf#networkx.readwrite.gexf.write_gexf).
The point of this function is to:

> Write G in GEXF format to path.

With `G` being a graph.

In order to obtain a `.gephi` file I would suggest opening the `.gexf` obtained from networkX with Gephi and saving as a `.gephi`.

Steps in pictures(example):

1. Write your graph as a `.gexf` file:

```py
some_graph = nx.path_graph(4)
nx.write_gexf(some_graph, "some_graph.gexf")
```

2. Open *Gephi* and select **Open Graph File...**:
   [image: Open graph file...]
3. Select **File>Save As...**
   [image: Save as...]
4. Next, choose **File Format: Gephi Files (*.gephi)**
   [image: Save as .gephi]

#### Something to have in mind:

According to the [Gephi Quick Start Tutorial](https://gephi.org/tutorials/gephi-tutorial-quick_start.pdf):

> Saving your project [as a .gephi file] encapsulates all data and results in a single session file.

The `.gephi` file format is meant to be used as a "session file", not to be used as an import file for Gephi.

Instead a specific file format(`.gexf`) was created by the Gephi project:

> GEXF (Graph Exchange XML Format) is a language for describing complex
> networks structures, their associated data and dynamics.

(see further info about this file format [here](https://gephi.org/gexf/format/))

#### In essence...

If you need/want a graph saved as a file, use one of [these formats](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats).
With GEXF always being the most liberating one(allowing more features).

However, If you need/want to save a session after manipulating a graph using Gephi, use `.gephi`.

#### Also, take into consideration the difference in size of the file formats:

For our example above:

- the original graph in GEFX format has a size of **714 bytes**.
- a blank session with the same GEFX graph imported in GEPHI format has a size of **8722 bytes**.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want to export it directly from python

Comment: A .gephi format is uniquely to be opened with Gephi and is not a representation of a graph. But rather, as far I can tell, a somewhat more complex representation of your **workspace on Gephi** after opening a graph(in any of these [supported formats](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/)). So I doubt there’s a way to extract it directly from Python.

Comment: If I can get references to back this up I will add this information to the answer

Comment: Check the last edit if this issue still concerns you. Glad to help with any further doubt :)

Comment: I totally agree with the very detailed answer of @willcrack. Extracting to .gephi directly from networkx is not supposed to be what networkx and Gephi are for. I would suggest you to be more specific with what you want to achieve by your approach because there are ways to reach a somewhat similar final result wrt layout, sizes, colors etc, therefore please be more specific.